# Bottom-Margin with varying content height

Tags: html, css, containers, margin, footer

I have a problem I have been trying to solve, but without any progress.

This is a summary of my code:

```css
body {
  background-image: url('img/bg_Body.gif');
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 880px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  top: 0px;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-image: url('img/faux_tile.png');
  min-height: 200px;
  padding-top: 105px;
  padding-right: 80px;
  min-width: 400px;
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-bottom: 110px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    Some content here (Varying height)
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I add a margin between the content and the end of the page?

The `faux_tile.png` covers to the end of the page, I want a margin between the end of the page and the faux_tile.png, which is a small margin showing `bg_Body.gif`.

Comment: As a side note, does `#content` really need to be `position: absolute`? Is there no other way to achieve what you want to achieve? (I can't judge that right now)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right:0;
    bottom:20px; /*this should give you 20px margin at the bottom*/
    background-image: url('img/faux_tile.png');
    min-height: 200px;
    padding-top: 105px;
    padding-right: 80px;
    min-width: 400px;
    padding-left: 80px;
    padding-bottom: 110px;
}
```

the other way could be to give `#container` a `min-height` of less than 100%

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestions, but both did not work for me. For the first, it caused the padding-bottom to increase or decreased the content's height. And no matter what value I put for #container min-height, it stays the same height, even if its like 500% height.

Comment: how about the same as above, but remove the `padding-bottom`

Comment: It showed a margin at the bottom, but decreased the #content height and some texts went out of #content.

Comment: ok, that's a good start. your total height will be `min-height` + `padding-bottom` + `padding-top` so if you add 20px in the bottom via `bottom:20px` then remove 20px from `min-height`

Comment: Hi, thanks but it still did not work. Can you help me edit my style.css to create a margin at the bottom? My files are here: http://www.mediafire.com/?lmnsfa1vinkc1q5 I need the margin to show the background image. Many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You could give `body` a `margin-bottom`.

That *should* force a margin even though your container is `position: absolute`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. The margin-bottom does not seem to work, as if I put margin-bottom: 900px; , it shows a margin around 100px, but when the content height increases, the margin decreases. I will need a fixed margin height regardless of the length of content.

Comment: @initialsHL ah, okay. Well, the reason why this is a problem is the `position: absolute`. Why do you need that in the first place? I can't really see the benefit in the scenario you present - is there more to it?

Comment: No I didn't specifically put position: absolute, it's just that Microsoft Expression Web 4 puts it as default when I added the <div>. Can you help me edit my file so that there will be a margin at the bottom showing the background image, regardless of the content's length? Here's my file: mediafire.com/?lmnsfa1vinkc1q5 Thank you very much!

Comment: @initials if you remove `position: absolute` giving the body a `margin-bottom` will work.